# talend - tMap output into list

Tags: sql, oracle, talend, talend-mdm

I have the following flow:

```
                                  tOutputFile (will output many fields)    
                                   /   
tOracleInput ->  tMap -> tReplicate
                                   \
                                  tMap (will only map the reference field)
                                     \
                                     tUniqRow (only unique reference field)
                                       \
                                     tSetGlobalVar 
                                        (and add to globalMap as a list--???)

   | (on subjob ok)
   |
   |
   |
   |
  \ /

tOracleInput  -------------------> tMap -------------------> tOutputFile
(filter where clause
with references from globalMap list)
```

But I'm at lost on how can I go about to put the output of `tUniqRow` to `tSetGlobalVar`? (The ??? above)
Or if not `tSetGLobalVar`, I can use `tJava` to put it in globalMap, but how can I get the output of `tUniqRow` in code level?

Can anyone enlighten me regarding this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tJavaflex after tUniqRow component.

--->tUniqRow---row1(uniques)-->tJavaFlex

-> In start code of tjavaFlex initialize a list  : List list = new ArrayList();

-> In main code of tJavaFlex add your tuniqRow flow to list variable : 
list.add(row1.yourColumn);

-> In end code of tJavaFlex add the list variable to globalMap : 
globalMap.put("KeyName",list);

Access this map using "keyName" anywhere.

Hope this helps..